# 'Expo' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, expo

I have given the right path of npm in environment variables and installed expo globally but still when i run expo command in cmd , it shows expo is not an internal or external command

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: Windows 10 Operating system

Comment: Try to install locally in your project folder and try..

Comment: do i need to give the local folder path to environment variable as well?

Comment: Did you install the [package `expo-cli`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/workflow/expo-cli/)?  That's what allows you to type `expo` at the command prompt when the path is set properly.

Comment: yeah and i installed it globally,